# Java prints array memory address rather than array contents

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have created a function which finds the maximum of groups of 3 in my array. When I come to print this, the memory address [I@43c46747 gets printed instead of the maximums which should be contained within the array.

I am not allowed to use any import statements/ anything advanced to solve this - trying to possibly use a helper function?

Thanks :)

Comment: Then write a loop to print each item of the array one by one.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, what you see is not a memory address, but array's class name and hash value (in hex form). This  is a behavior inherited from `toString()` method of `java.lang.Object`

You can use a for-loop to print each array element individually.

eg.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

Note that `println` prints the result of `toString` method of the array elements for non-primitive types. Make sure their `toString` is properly overriden if you want custom behaviour rather than "classname@hashvalue"

Answer (score 0):

When you try to print an Array normally, you are simply calling to `toString()` method on an Array object. In Java, this is the default implementation which prints out a result like you saw above `[I@43c46747`.

You should use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

to print meaningful values for an Array.

Comment: "*I am not allowed to use any import statements...*"

Comment: @Pshemo `java.util.Arrays.toString(myArray);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis While technically correct I doubt that OP teacher will appreciate it :)